# How to set the active tool in the composerview?

Tags: pyqgis

This script works fine for me, but when setting the active tool, its active but not marked as active in the gui (still the default tool is highlighted):

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis import gui

scale = 10000
templateFile='c:/1temp/mylayout.qpt'
activetool = 15# 'MoveItemContent'

composerview = iface.createNewComposer()
#load template
f= file(templateFile, 'r')
templateContent = f.read()
f.close()
doc=QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(templateContent)
composerview.composition().loadFromTemplate(doc)
#show composer
composerview.show()
#setup map
map = composerview.composition().getComposerMapById(0)#QgsComposerMap
#extent
map.zoomToExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
#scale
if scale >0:
    map.setNewScale(int(scale))
#set activetool
if activetool is not None and activetool<>'':
    composerview.setCurrentTool(gui.QgsComposerView.Tool(activetool))
#finally
composerview.composition().refreshItems()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a interesting question,maybe is a bug.

to give you a "solution", you can try something like this.

Add this code at the end of the script.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

win = composerview.composerWindow()
items_widget = win.findChildren(QtGui.QActionGroup)

for action in items_widget[0].actions():
    if not action.isSeparator():
        print('  action: %s (%s)' % (action.text(), action.isChecked()))
        if action.text()=="Move &Content":
            action.setChecked(True)
```